# Can one macOS laptop machine display and control another macOS machine but not remote desktop or something?

Tags: keyboard, display, mouse, kvm

I have two macOS machines. One of them is a laptop. Right now I have them both hooked up to a KVM to share an external monitor and keyboard and mouse.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use my laptop macOS machine to control the other one? So the monitor, keyboard, and mouse on my laptop one would connect to my other macOS. That way I don't need a KVM and can just use the monitor+keyboard+mouse on my laptop plus the external monitor hooked up to the laptop.

And I do not mean remote desktop or VNC. I know how those work and that is not what I want. I am interested in more of a first party connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is YES, you can!   And it's built right in to newer MacOS versions.  The feature you're looking for is called Universal Control.   Apple's documentation for the feature can be found here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212757

Apple's description of Universal Control:

> Universal Control: Use a single keyboard and mouse between Mac and
> iPad Use the keyboard, mouse, or trackpad of your Mac to control up to
> two other nearby Mac or iPad devices, and work seamlessly between
> them.

Comment: But how? It doesn’t say how!

Comment: Huh @2540625?  The article talks about how to set it up, arrange the displays, controlling the devices,etc.   Everything you need should be there :)

Comment: It says basically, “turn it on, put your devices near each other, it just works”. Except it doesn’t.